# Bootstrapping Hybrid Angular 1+2 Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

Following the official [5 min QuickStart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) I have a simple Angular 2 app working.

I set up Angular 1 and have now them both working independently, see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P4H8eUQvQeTZRJHi3g10?p=preview).

Following the [official upgrade guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) they say:

> To then switch the application into hybrid mode, we must first install
>   Angular 2 to the project. Follow the instructions in the [QuickStart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)
>   for some pointers on this. When we have Angular 2 installed, we can
>   import and instantiate the `UpgradeAdapter`, and then call its `bootstrap`
>   method. It is designed to take the exact same arguments as
>   angular.bootstrap so that it is easy to make the switch:
>
> ```
> import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
>
> /* . . . */
>
> const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
>
> upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp'], {strictDi: true});
> ```

My question is **where to place it**?

It sounds like a 'do my job' question but it's not so. I guess in `main.ts`, but I tried a lot of things without success. The doc is not really clear about this and some tutorials of 1 month old are already outdated.

**--- update:**

In my case I forgot to load upgrade.js that I thought already included

Answer (score 4):

I had a look at your plunkr. In fact you can use several times `bootstrap` but this means that you use two different applications into your HTML page.

If you want to mix Angular1 and Angular2 stuff into the same application, you need to call only the `boostrap` method of the `UpgradeAdapter`.

The call of the `boostrap` function on the `UpgradeAdapter` and it's creation could be done in the `boot.ts` file:

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';

var upgrade = new UpgradeAdapter();

// Configure the upgrade adapter
(...)

export function main() {
  try {
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp']);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

You can import this into your HTML file like this:

```
<script>
  System.import('app/main').then(function(src) {
    src.main();
  });
</script>
```

**Mixing Angular2 and Angular1 stuff**

If you want to **bootstrap an Angular2 application**, provide the main component as first parameter and the provider for the Angular1 application to be able to use factories / services / directives into the Angular2 application.

```
// Providers for Angular1 elements
upgrade.upgradeNg1Provider('customService');
upgrade.upgradeNg1Provider('customFactory');

// Providers for Angular2 elements
upgrade.addProvider(HTTP_PROVIDERS);

// Bootstrap Angular2 application
upgrade.bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

If you want an **Angular1 application to use Angular2 stuff**, you need to provide the document.element as first parameter of the `bootstrap` method:

```
// Providers for Angular2 elements
upgrade.downgradeNg2Provider(HTTP_PROVIDERS);

upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp']);
```

This plunkr could also be useful to you: http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg?p=preview.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed and clear help! I think you put on light the problem: the file upgrade.dev.js was missing. What sounds crazy is the official doc doesn't mention it, like if upgrade.js was loaded by default with angular2.

Comment: You're welcome! It's clear that the upgrade.dev.js is needed ;-) The doc should underline this...