# How to import the angular upgrade adapter to get a hybrid application?

Tags: angularjs, angular, systemjs, ng-upgrade

I looked at at the official upgrade guide, some blogs [like this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html) but I don't get it.
I wanted to take a look at the upgrade module of angular2, but failed right at the beginning when I tried to bootstrap my ng1 application with the angular upgrade adapter to start.

[I get those errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VOpG.png)

My index.html

```
<html>
<head>
   (...)
   <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>

   <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        (...)
    </div>

<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.controller.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ts (from the official upgrade guide)

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';

const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], {strictDi: true});
```

it's fine to bootstrap like this

```
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], {strictDi: true});
```

if I only miss some sort of polyfill here is my package.json:

```
{
 (...)
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.9",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.14",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  }
}
```

I'm using the tsconfig.json and typings.json from the official 5min quickstart.

Everywhere I read it seems that this is a trivial task, but although I tried different approches none worked for me. So what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

The solution is as Thierry stated below to import

```
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js"></script
```

You can find more details in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361246/bootstrapping-hybrid-angular-12-application) which focuses on the same problem (I've actually read it bevore but missed the comment with the important part for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to include the `upgrade` js file:

```
 <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>    
 <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js"></script>
```

See this plunkr for more details:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg?p=preview

Comment: Thank you that's it! Perfect. 
Could you explain why there are two files (upgrade.js and upgrade.dev.js)? They seem to have the exact same code.

Comment: I wondered because I don't have a minified version (angular beta.14) so both are the same, but you will probably be right for the future.
Just wanted to make sure I don't is something.